# AngularJS, Angular-Material - HTML Not rendering despite object present on $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have searched extensively for a solution to this problem and can't seem to find one. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

**The Basics:**

- Utilizing angular-material tabs
- Upon selection of an item from a dropdown, a call is made to a firebase database and returns a response, which is put into an array on the $scope.
- HTML is utilizing ng-repeat on this response object.

**The Problem:**

- Despite the response object being present on the scope, the html does not render anything until the user "clicks" another button on the view - any button at all. In fact, the user has to simply touch/click something on the screen and then the results render.
- If user makes a call to the database to get artists in a certain medium (i.e. painting), but does not click anything on the screen, no results will show at all, despite response object being present in $scope.

I am stumped.

**HTML:**

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-center-tabs><md-tab label="Artists">
    <md-content id="tab_background" class="md-padding">
        <div class="query_results hide_link" layout-padding>
            <a ng-repeat="artist in results  | filter: searchText"
               href="/#/artist/{{artist.selectedMedium}}/{{artist.uid}}">
                <md-card>
                    <img ng-src="{{artist.profImg}}" class="md-card-image" alt="Washed Out">
                    <md-card-header>
                        <div id="card_play_button_included">
                            <md-card-header-text>
                                <span class="hide_link md-title">{{artist.name}}{{artist.name_last}}</span>
                                <span class="hide_link md-subhead">{{artist.selectedSubmedium[0]}}</span>
                                <span class="hide_link md-caption">{{artist.neighborhood}}</span>
                            </md-card-header-text>
                        </div>
                    </md-card-header>
                    <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                    </md-card-actions>
                </md-card>
            </a>
        </div>
    </md-content>
    </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Events">
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

**Javascript:**

```
  $scope.getArtists = function(medium){
    //resetting results array
    $scope.firstArray = [];
    $scope.results = [];
    var Medium = medium.name;
    firebase.database().ref('/Artists/' + Medium).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
      console.log(snapshot.val());
      var obj = snapshot.val();
      for (var key in obj) {
        var innerObj = obj[key]
        innerObj.uid = key;
        console.log(innerObj);
        $scope.firstArray.push(innerObj);
      }
      $scope.results = $scope.firstArray;
      $scope.runSpinner();
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used $scope.apply() and it solved it.